# Edit background on Wordpress CSS style sheet

Tags: css, wordpress

I'd like to edit some background properties on my Wordpress site.

Using Chrome's Inspect Element I can see that currently I have:

```
body.custom-background {
background-color: #f6f6f6;
background-image: url('http://patchwood.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/bktopright.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: top left;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I would like to edit background-repeat to no-repeat and background-position to right.

Sounds simple but when I look in the Editor in Wordpress the selector does not exist. It turns out that this styling appears to be within the html on line 53 of the home page.

If it was a handcoded website I would just update the stylesheet but since it's a database driven Wordpress site it's more difficult to know where to edit.

I wonder if there is a means of adding styling to the body element background that overrides any other properties? So basically, if I was to add to the very bottom of the stylesheet the following code to override anything else.

```
 body.custom-background {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
}
```

I did try just adding that but with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: It's kinda bad practice, but you can just use !important

Comment: @AndrewBartel thanks I just tried this at the very bottom of the stylesheet I do have access to:
body.custom-background {
 background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
 background-position: top right !important;
 }
But that hasn't helped. Wonder if I've got the selector wrong

Comment: Can you post the rest of the relevant code? If the above didn't work you're doing something else wrong ..

Comment: @Adrift I'm not sure what else would be relevant? Here is the site: tinyurl.com/m562wgd if you can suggest anything?

Comment: You have error in `style.css` because you inserted the selector `body.custom-background` in `@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {` (you haven't closed the Braces `}` ) which means that the `no-reapeat` is **working only if the browser width is smaller than 400px**. So you should insert `}` before `body.custom-background` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its showing up in the header - by the looks of it - its probably a custom background image set in the wordpress backend.

a rather round about way of fixing this can be to add

```
<style>
body.custom-background {
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: top right !important;
}
</style>
```

to your header or footer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's hard-coded, as you suggest.  It's located within the `<head>` tag, which means it's probably part of header.php.  Instead of editing style.css, why not look in header.php and change it there (or better yet, delete the reference in `<head>` and move `.custom-background`'s style information to style.css)?

**Edit** According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds), custom backgrounds are enabled using the following line in functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
```

Removing this line (and then setting your desired background properties in style.css) should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the info I like the idea of this answer I'm just having a hard time with it because header.php does not containt he string "custom-background". I've actually gone through every file searching for it - I cannot tell where it's being generated from!
The Wordpress theme allows one to select a background picture from the WP backend. My knowledge of dynamic sites a litte hazy but could it be that the content is in a SQL database?

Comment: Wait, does header.php not even contain `custom-background` even as a class for `<body>`?  In that case maybe it's being assigned by some function somewhere else...found it!  It should be in functions.php - see my edited answer.

Comment: thanks for the help on this. I did try removing that line from functions.php and adding my own custom styling but what happened is that the background disappeared all together. I could not seem to select the body background (tried both body and body.custom-background to no avail. Having done a quick bit of research it appears using !important should be a last resort which is why I wanted to go with your answer but alas I failed. Not sure how close I was there but sincerely, thank again for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

> i have to manage background in inspect element css this is success css
>   code:

```
<style>
body.custom-background {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    background-image: url("http://patchwood.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/bktopright.png");
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
</style>
```